# Moment of inertia and gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, moment-of-inertia, inertia

Would the objects have moment of Inertia if there was no gravity?
Because imagine a bar, if I put my hand at the center of the bar and rotate it, it would be easier than rotate the bar picking one extremity of the bar, and I think it is because gravity acts on each piece of the bar and pull it down, difficulting the upwards rotation. So, in space would the objects have moment of inertia?
Probably Yes, but that's difficult to imagine, so that's Why I'm asking.

Comment: Related question for mass: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81373/2451

Comment: So I would assume moment of inertia is inherent to the mass/matter, not to Weight. But what was confusing me is that it is much more difficult to rotate due to weight, and if it would be related to moment of inertia

Answer (score 3):

See moment of inertia is analogous to mass. Moment of inertia can be thought of as a physical "property" of the object similar to that of mass. And as we know that mass does not depend on any force or gravitational field or any other external effect, so does moment of inertia. Hope this answers your question.